# Error: table does not exist (clearly it does)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have in my database this table `Cast` with columns `ID` and `Actor` for example

```
ID  | Actor
----+------
123 | Michael Douglas
123 | Robert Duval
```

I would like to return columns `ID` and `Cast` in my cursor for a specific ID

```
public Cursor getCastCursor(String ID){

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String[] sqlSelect = new String[]{"ID","Actor"};
        String[] selectionArg = new String[]{ID};

        qb.setTables("Cast");
        Cursor c = qb.query(
                db,           //SQLiteDatabase db
                sqlSelect,    //String[] projectionIn
                "ID=?",       //String selection
                selectionArg, //String[] selectionArgs
                null,         //String groupBy
                null,         //String having
                null);        //String sortOrder
        c.moveToFirst();

        return c;
}
```

I keep getting this error, and sure why

> no such table: Cast (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT ID, Actor FROM Cast WHERE (ID=?)

**edit**

Here is a picture of my database. Clearly the table exists.

[image]

I create the database using Python

```
#Add countries, genres, directors, and actors tables 
def createTables(source):
    with sqlite3.connect(source) as connection:
        c = connection.cursor()
        c.execute("""Select * from Movies""")
        all_data = c.fetchall()
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Countries(ID TEXT,Country TEXT)""")
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Actors(ID TEXT, Actor TEXT)""")
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Genres(ID TEXT,Genre TEXT)""")
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Directors(ID TEXT,Director TEXT)""")

        for single_data in all_data:
            countries = returnCommaDelimitedList(single_data[18])
            directors = returnCommaDelimitedList(single_data[8])
            genres = returnCommaDelimitedList(single_data[6])
            actors = returnCommaDelimitedList(single_data[10])
            for single_actor in actors:
                c.execute("INSERT INTO Actors VALUES(?,?);",(single_data[0],single_actor))
            for single_country in countries:
                c.execute("INSERT INTO Countries VALUES(?,?);",(single_data[0],single_country))
            for single_director in directors:
                c.execute("INSERT INTO Directors VALUES(?,?);",(single_data[0],single_director))
            for single_genre in genres:
                c.execute("INSERT INTO Genres VALUES(?,?);",(single_data[0],single_genre))
```

Comment: It might be complaining about `Cast.Cast`. Perhaps you should rename you table to `Actors` and/or column to `name`

Comment: I tried that already

Comment: @suku no ID is defined as a string

Comment: If you tried to rename the table or column without recreating the database, then yes, the table name of "Cast" cannot be found

Comment: @cricket_007 I recreated and the database with the right column name. Still not working.

Comment: It says that the table name is wrong- "no such table: Cast" alternatively check if the column name is ID and not id or Id

Comment: Can you please show your `CREATE TABLE` statement and where you create the database handler in order to call this method?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added code as requested including a picture from my database browser

Comment: Okay, so, how are you now copying that database file into your android device? That seems to be the issue here. Also, wondering why the ids aren't primary integer keys

Comment: @cricket_007 So I cleaned, rebuilt, and remade my project and then uninstalled and reinstalled the app and that did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

So I cleaned, rebuilt, and remade my project and then uninstalled and reinstalled the app and that did the trick.